# How to migrate to new React lifecycle API?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

As you know some lifecycle methods like `componentWillReceiveProps` are now deprecated.

Well, my code used this lifecycle method and now I have no idea how to migrate to the new API of React.

Here is how I used:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.newPost) {
        this.props.posts.unshift(nextProps.newPost);
    }
}
```

In the react blog I could read that...

> Together with componentDidUpdate, this new lifecycle should cover all
>   use cases for the legacy componentWillReceiveProps.

... but how to implement this?

Comment: Well, basically the React team is pointing (as you mentioned) to `componentDidMount` or perhaps use one of the techniques discussed here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops , `componentDidUpdate` has access to the component's state a props directly, like: `this.props` and `this.state`. Finally this part of your code caught my attention: `this.props.posts.unshift(nextProps.newPost);` are you mutating the `posts` array directly on the component's `props`?.  That looks like a **no-no** to me.

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidUpdate()` is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.

Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated. This is also a good place to do network requests as long as you compare the current props to previous props (e.g. a network request may not be necessary if the props have not changed).

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.userID !== prevProps.userID) {
    this.fetchData(this.props.userID);
  }
}
```

Note that it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or you’ll cause an infinite loop.

Comment: This causes an extra render which shouldn't be necessary. Is there another solution? getDerivedStateFromProps could be used in conjunction with caching props in state, but that's awkward.

Answer (score 0):

you can use getDerivedStateFromProps or componentDidMount, there is sequence to running lifecycles :

1. getDerivedStateFromProps
2. shouldComponentUpdate
3. render
4. getSnapshotBeforeUpdate
5. componentDidUpdate