# How to remove componentWillReceiveProps for component which aggregates props in state

Tags: reactjs

I have a class component which accepts a timeseries datapoint as a prop. Each time it receives a new datapoint it adds the point to a collection in state (to a limit of 7s worth of data). Currently in `componentWillReceiveProps`:

```
if (nextProps.data && this.props.data !== nextProps.data) {
  let { collection } = this.state
  collection = collection
    .addDatapoint(nextProps.data)
    .deduplicate() //removes duplicate entries
    .leftTrim(7000) //removes old entries as needed to prevent time window from exceeding 7 seconds

  this.setState({...this.state, collection})
}
```

In `render` I plot a D3 timeseries chart using `this.state.collection`.

I'm struggling with how to implement this in response to `componentWillReceiveProps` deprecation. [React docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) claim `getDerivedStateFromProps` should be used sparingly and they provide examples of how to implement some things without it by using the `render` method but I fail to see how that can be accomplished here without calling `setState` in `render` which I think is considered bad practice.

Even using `getDerivedStateFromProps`, there is no access to previous props, so my condition that looks for a change in the data prop can't be implemented unless I copy `data` to `this.state.previousProps.data` which feels awkward.

I'm looking for suggestions for ways to re-implement this that is compatible with the future direction of React.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to migrate to new React lifecycle API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51655279/how-to-migrate-to-new-react-lifecycle-api)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `componentDidUpdate` method.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.data && prevProps.data !== this.props.data) {
        let { collection } = this.state
        collection = collection
        .addDatapoint(this.props.data)
        .deduplicate() //removes duplicate entries
        .leftTrim(7000) //removes old entries as needed to prevent time window from exceeding 7 seconds

        this.setState({...this.state, collection})
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but won't this cause an (unnecessary) additional render?

Comment: So without a render how the charts will reflect with new data set? Do you want to show the new data set in your chart right?

Comment: That's true. `componentDidUpdate` will cause additional render. One when the props are changed from parent, and one after setState in `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: So in summary we are forced to either cache props in state and utilize `getDerivedStateFromProps` (ugly) or use `componentDidUpdate` (doubles number of renders)